# Print className, method name and line number of exceptiopn using log4j in single line log

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to print class name, method name and line number of exception in single line using log4j.

For that , i am looking at.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

I want to get logged in following format:

2015-03-03 16:18:30,480 Testing for for log4j java.lang.NullPointerException  com.test.Piyush main 40

But i am getting every thing in new line.

```
2015-03-03 16:18:30,480 Testing for for log4j java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.Piyush.main(Piyush.java:40)
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.Piyush.main(Piyush.java:40)
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.Piyush.main(Piyush.java:40)
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.Piyush.main(Piyush.java:40)
```

used Log4j configuration:

```
log4j.logger.com.myLogger=INFO, mylogFile
log4j.appender.mylogFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.mylogFile.File=logs/infibeam.log
log4j.appender.mylogFile.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.mylogFile.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.mylogFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.mylogFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %m %throwable{short.className}  %throwable{"short.methodName"} %throwable{"short.lineNumber"} %throwable{short.message}
```

Comment: I guess you'll have to process the output from `printStackTrace` in Java such that it becomes a single-line string.

Comment: This is one way to do it...For that i need to change code in entire project,  As of Now, It is not feasible for me to do change in entire project.

Comment: Then you need an alternative to `org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout` that does it for you. I don't now if such a thing exists, but you could presumably build and install one without affecting your source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `org.apache.log4j.Layout` class and override `public String format(LoggingEvent event)` method to generate any output format you want.

Then use your custom layout to define the appender in `log4j.properties` file.

Custom Layout Class:

```
public class MyCustomLayout extends Layout {

    @Override
    public void activateOptions()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        //Your formatting code goes here
        //You can access all information in event and generate the format you want
        String output = "Your custome log format";

        return output;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean ignoresThrowable() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use custom layout in your log4.properties file

`log4j.appender.myappender.layout=MyCustomLayout`